# How would a form_for a Timesheet application work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, erb

I have the following ActiveRecord models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :timesheets
end

class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :work_days
end

class WorkDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :timesheet
end
```

The `WorkDay` model has attributes like `hours`, `days`, `comments`, etc.

I can not figure out how the form would look like in rails for this.. I saw some complex forms from railscasts but still not getting it.

I am envisioning a form like below (for 7 days):

```
06/19 (Day1)  06/20 (Day2)  06/21 (Day3)  ...  06/26 (Day 7)
textfield 1   textfield 2   textfield 3   ...  textfield4

<submit>
```

So I have 7 textfields in this form (might have comments for each one as well).

Can someone tell me/explain me how the `form_for` would look for this.

Answer (score 0):

You will be having something like this -

```
<%= form_for @timesheet do |f| %>

 # Fields for @timesheet attributes.     
 <% f.fields_for 7.times.map{@timesheet.workd_day.new}.each do |t| %>
   Hour: <%= t.text_field hour %>
   Days: <%= t.text_field days %>
   Comments: #one more fields for block for comments.
 <% end %>

 <%= f.sumit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```